# Split PHP array into two arrays based on associate keys

Tags: php, arrays

How do I split an associate array into two arrays given the keys that I would like to keep in the first resultant array?

For instance...

```
//Given:
$myArray=array('a'=>123,'b'=>'ABC','c'=>321,'d'=>'CBA','e'=>111);
$split=array('a','c');

//Obtain all elements who's keys are in $split
$newArray1=array('a'=>123,'c'=>321);
//Obtain all elements who's keys are not in $split
$newarray2=array('b'=>'ABC','d'=>'CBA','e'=>111);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No frills:

```
$newArray1 = [];
$newArray2 = [];

foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $split)) {
        $newArray1[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $newArray2[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Frills:

```
$newArray1 = array_intersect_key($myArray, array_flip($split));
$newArray2 = array_diff_key($myArray, $newArray1);
```

See also: [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip) [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/array_diff_key)

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I was planning on using something like the no frills version, but didn't know if there was a better way.  Any recommendations on which version to use?

Comment: @user1032531 Well, how big are your arrays and how big is `$split`? Typically I would benchmark both algorithms and see whether the more concise version is worth the penalty (if any).

Comment: The array is less than twenty elements.  Probably doesn't mater, but for the sake of principle would like to do it right.  Also, would you recommend sending a larger or smaller `$split` since it returns the same thing but switches the arrays.

Comment: @user1032531 What do you mean by "sending a larger or smaller `$split`?

Comment: If `$myArray` is 20 elements, and `$split` has 4 of those elements, then `$newArray` has 4 elements and `$newArray2` has 16 elements.  Alternatively, `$split` could have 16 elements, and the reverse is true.

Comment: @user1032531 Moving the wedge won't make a real difference; the same number of items are iterated over.